# NumPy Creating two matrices that results in third that calculates diagonal

Tags: numpy, matrix, random, printing

I am rather new to coding in python but familiar with matlab and Mathematica.

In python, I created two 4x4 matrices (A and B) that have random number elements which in turn creates a third C matrix like:
[image: matrix c]

The diagonal elements should then be presented in 4x2 matrix but I can not construct it right.

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(4,4)
B = np.random.rand(4,4)
C = np.array([[A[0,0], A[0,1], B[0,2], B[0,3]],
              [A[1,0], A[1,1], B[1,2], B[1,3]],
              [A[2,0], A[2,1], B[2,2], B[2,3]],
              [A[3,0], A[3,1], B[3,2], B[3,3]]])
```

**My question is, how do I print out the diagonal from Matrix C from here? The output checked in other software should be something like:**

`C = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4], [ 5,  6,  7,  8], [ 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]`

and then the diagonal

`Diagonal = [[1, 6], [10, 15], [3, 8], [12, 16]]`

Comment: There are two things that are confusing me: 1), your current code creates matrix C only from half of A and B. Why? and how does the attached image relate? 2), I don't understand your desired Diagonal output. How is it constructed? For me, the diagonal from your example C would be the array [1, 6, 11, 16]

Comment: Your "Diagonal" doesn't look like a diagonal to me. For `C` I would use `C = np.c_[A[:, :2], B[:, 2:]]`

Comment: @chrysophylaxs

It need to be presented in 2 by 4 matrix the output. If you disregard from the output i presented, what would you do further? Thank you

Comment: @Kaysersöze, I don't know how to fill the 2 by 4 output, so I cannot help you. Please provide more info

Comment: If you have this working in MATLAB, showing that code might help - I used to use that, and can test code in Octave.   But I agree with others, your example is confusing.

Comment: That detailed `C` looks like `np.hstack((A[:,:2],B[:,-2:])`, joining parts of 2 arrays on the 2nd dimension.  That's nothing like `((A,B),(B,A))`.  `np.diagonal` and `np.diag` give diagonals, or direct advanced indexing, eg.  `A[range(4),range(4)]`